Custom Payment Provider for Mollie Failed to Complete Flow and Create Order
I have created a custom payment provider for Mollie using the steps mentioned in the docs. I am able to initiate and complete the payment, but when the payment is complete and the webhook event getWebhookActionAndData is triggered, I am getting the following error. Due to this, I am unable to place an order.
package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "@medusajs/admin-sdk": "latest",
    "@medusajs/cli": "latest",
    "@medusajs/framework": "latest",
    "@medusajs/medusa": "latest",
    "@mikro-orm/core": "5.9.7",
    "@mikro-orm/knex": "5.9.7",
    "@mikro-orm/migrations": "5.9.7",
    "@mikro-orm/postgresql": "5.9.7",
    "@mollie/api-client": "^4.1.0",
    "awilix": "^8.0.1",
    "medusa-interfaces": "^1.3.10",
    "pg": "^8.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@medusajs/test-utils": "latest",
    "@mikro-orm/cli": "5.9.7",
    "@swc/core": "1.5.7",
    "@swc/jest": "^0.2.36",
    "@types/express": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.13",
    "@types/node": "^20.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.25",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.6.2",
    "vite": "^5.2.11"
  },

Errors In backend console

   message: 'payment - id must be defined'
error: An error occurred while processing payment.webhook_received
error: payment - id must be defined
{
  message: 'payment - id must be defined',
  name: 'Error',
  stack: 'Error: payment - id must be defined\n' +
    '    at AbstractService_.retrieve (/home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/utils/src/modules-sdk/medusa-internal-service.ts:122:15)\n' +
    '    at AbstractService_.descriptor.value (/home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/utils/src/modules-sdk/decorators/inject-manager.ts:54:29)\n' +
    '    at PaymentModuleService.capturePayment_ (/home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/payment/src/services/payment-module.ts:633:24)\n' +
    '    at transaction.transaction (/home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/utils/src/modules-sdk/decorators/inject-transaction-manager.ts:63:39)\n' +
    '    at fork.getConnection.transactional (/home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/EntityManager.js:774:35)\n' +
    '    at PostgreSqlConnection.transactional (/home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@mikro-orm/knex/AbstractSqlConnection.js:36:31)\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n' +
    '    at async transactionWrapper (/home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/utils/src/dal/utils.ts:32:10)\n' +
    '    at async MikroOrmBaseRepository.transaction (/home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/utils/src/dal/mikro-orm/mikro-orm-repository.ts:74:12)\n' +
    '    at async PaymentModuleService.descriptor.value (/home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/utils/src/modules-sdk/decorators/inject-transaction-manager.ts:32:14)\n' +
    '⮑ sat /home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/core-flows/dist/payment/workflows/capture-payment.js: [capture-payment-workflow -> capture-payment-step (invoke)]\n' +
    '⮑ sat /home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/core-flows/dist/payment/workflows/process-payment.js: [process-payment-workflow -> capture-payment-workflow-as-step (invoke)]',
  __isMedusaError: true,
  type: 'not_found',
  code: undefined,
  date: 2024-12-04T23:20:47.751Z
}

Logs from admin dash workflow

  Error Logs

{
  "id": "wf_exec_01JE9ZKPV6QNRJBMVBR9RJRNE3",
  "workflow_id": "complete-cart",

  "errors": [
    {
      "error": {
        "name": "Error",
        "stack": "Error: You must pass a non-undefined value to the property currency_code of entity Cart.\n    at Function.assignProperty (/home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/entity/EntityAssigner.js:46:19)\n    at /home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/entity/EntityAssigner.js:31:35\n    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)\n    at Function.assign (/home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/entity/EntityAssigner.js:30:27)\n    at SqlEntityManager.assign (/home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/EntityManager.js:995:40)\n    at /home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/utils/src/dal/mikro-orm/mikro-orm-repository.ts:437:17\n    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n    at MikroOrmAbstractBaseRepository_.update (/home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/utils/src/dal/mikro-orm/mikro-orm-repository.ts:436:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at async AbstractService_.update (/home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/utils/src/modules-sdk/medusa-internal-service.ts:348:14)\n⮑ sat /home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/core-flows/dist/cart/workflows/complete-cart.js: [complete-cart -> update-carts (invoke)]",
        "message": "You must pass a non-undefined value to the property currency_code of entity Cart."
      },
      "action": "update-carts",
      "handlerType": "compensate"
    }
  ],
  "execution": {
    "state": "failed",

    "modelId": "complete-cart",
    "options": {
      "name": "complete-cart",
      "store": true,
      "idempotent": true,
      "retentionTime": 259200,
      "storeExecution": true
    },
    "metadata": {
      "sourcePath": "/home/al-sirang/Desktop/office-projects/medusa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/core-flows/dist/cart/workflows/complete-cart.js",
      "eventGroupId": "01JE9ZKPTNWTZT8KPY1A92FKWP",
      "parentStepIdempotencyKey": "process-payment-workflow:01JE9ZKPTNAC5HZD5A48MHJNG3:complete-cart-as-step:invoke"
    }
  },
  "state": "failed"
}


MolliePaymentProviderService implementation
type MollieOptions = {
  apiKey: string;
  profileId?: string;
  testMode?: boolean;
  webhookUrl?: string;
  redirectUrl?: string;
};

class MolliePaymentProviderService extends AbstractPaymentProvider<MollieOptions> {
  static identifier = "mollie";
  protected options_: MollieOptions;
  private mollieClient: ReturnType<typeof MollieClient>;

  static validateOptions(options: Record<any, any>) {
    if (!options.apiKey) {
      throw new MedusaError(
        MedusaError.Types.INVALID_DATA,
        "API key is required in the provider's options."
      );
    }
  }
  constructor(
    container: Record<string, any> & MedusaContainer,
    options: MollieOptions
  ) {
    super(container, options);
    this.options_ = options;
    this.mollieClient = MollieClient({
      apiKey: options.apiKey,
    });
  }

  async initiatePayment(
    context: CreatePaymentProviderSession
  ): Promise<PaymentProviderError | PaymentProviderSessionResponse> {
    try {
      const { currency_code, amount } = context;

      const formattedAmount = (amount as number).toFixed(2);

      const payment = await this.mollieClient.payments.create({
        method: PaymentMethod.creditcard, /// test payment method to creditCard (for testing)
        amount: {
          currency: currency_code.toUpperCase(),
          value: formattedAmount,
        },
        description: "Payment for order",
        redirectUrl: `${process.env.MOLLIE_REDIRECT_URL}`,
        webhookUrl: `${this.options_.webhookUrl}/hooks/payment/mollie_mollie`,
        // Only add customer details if they exist
        ...(context.context?.email && {
          billingEmail: context.context.email,
        }),
        metadata: {
          // Add metadata only if customer exists
          ...(context.context?.customer?.id && {
            customerId: context.context.customer.id,
            has_account: context.context.customer.has_account,
          }),
          session_id: context.context.session_id,
        },
      });

      const initiatePayment: Record<string, unknown> = payment as any;

      return {
        data: initiatePayment,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return this.handleError(error);
    }
  }

  async getPaymentStatus(
    paymentSessionData: Record<string, unknown>
  ): Promise<PaymentSessionStatus> {
    const payment = await this.mollieClient.payments.get(
      paymentSessionData.id as string
    );

    return this.mapPaymentStatus(payment.status);
  }

  async retrievePayment(
    paymentSessionData: Record<string, unknown>
  ): Promise<Record<string, unknown> | PaymentProviderError> {
    try {
      const payment = await this.mollieClient.payments.get(
        paymentSessionData.id as string
      );

      return {
        id: payment.id,
        status: payment.status,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return this.handleError(error);
    }
  }

  async authorizePayment(paymentSessionData: Record<string, unknown>): Promise<
    | PaymentProviderError
    | {
        status: PaymentSessionStatus;
        data: PaymentProviderSessionResponse["data"];
      }
  > {
    try {
      const externalId = paymentSessionData.id as string;

      const payment = await this.mollieClient.payments.get(externalId);

      return {
        status: this.mapPaymentStatus(payment.status),
        data: {
          ...payment,
          session_id: (payment.metadata as Record<string, any>).session_id,
          id: externalId,
          amount: payment.amount.value,
          currency_code: payment.amount.currency,
        },
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return this.handleError(error);
    }
  }
  /// todo: change this method to an Object
  private mapPaymentStatus(status: string): PaymentSessionStatus {
    switch (status) {
      case "paid":
        return PaymentSessionStatus.CAPTURED;
      case "authorized":
        return PaymentSessionStatus.AUTHORIZED;
      case "canceled":
        return PaymentSessionStatus.CANCELED;
      case "pending":
        return PaymentSessionStatus.PENDING;
      case "expired":
        return PaymentSessionStatus.ERROR;
      default:
        return PaymentSessionStatus.PENDING;
    }
  }

  private handleError(error: any): PaymentProviderError {
    console.error("Mollie Payment Provider Error:", error);
    return {
      error: error,
      code: error.response?.status || "unknown",
      detail: error?.response?.data?.detail || error.message,
    };
  }

  async updatePayment(
    context: UpdatePaymentProviderSession
  ): Promise<PaymentProviderError | PaymentProviderSessionResponse> {
    try {
      /// this method is not invoked
      const { amount, currency_code, data, context: customerDetails } = context;
      const externalId = data.id;
      /// todo: handle update logic
      const payment = await this.mollieClient.payments.update(
        externalId as string,
        {
          description: "",
        }
      );

      return {
        data: {
          id: payment.id,
          status: payment.status,
        },
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return this.handleError(error);
    }
  }

  async deletePayment(
    paymentSessionData: Record<string, unknown>
  ): Promise<PaymentProviderError | Record<string, unknown>> {
    return this.cancelPayment(paymentSessionData);
  }

  async capturePayment(
    paymentData: Record<string, unknown>
  ): Promise<PaymentProviderError | Record<string, unknown>> {
    try {
      const externalId = paymentData.id as string;
      const payment = await this.mollieClient.payments.get(externalId);

      return {
        ...payment,
        id: externalId,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return this.handleError(error);
    }
  }

  async refundPayment(
    paymentData: Record<string, unknown>,
    refundAmount: number
  ): Promise<PaymentProviderError | Record<string, unknown>> {
    try {
      const refund = await this.mollieClient.paymentRefunds.create({
        paymentId: paymentData.id as string,
        amount: {
          currency: paymentData.currency_code as string,
          value: `${refundAmount.toFixed(2)}`,
        },
      });

      return {
        id: refund.id,
        status: refund.status,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return this.handleError(error);
    }
  }

  async cancelPayment(
    paymentData: Record<string, unknown>
  ): Promise<PaymentProviderError | Record<string, unknown>> {
    try {
      // Use the stored paymentId from the session data
      const paymentId = paymentData.id as string;
      if (!paymentId) {
        throw new Error("No payment ID found");
      }

      const payment = await this.mollieClient.payments.get(paymentId);

      return {
        id: payment.id,
        status: "canceled",
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return this.handleError(error);
    }
  }

  async getWebhookActionAndData(
    payload: ProviderWebhookPayload["payload"]
  ): Promise<WebhookActionResult> {
    try {
      const { data } = payload;

      const payment = await this.mollieClient.payments.get(data.id as string);

      switch (payment.status) {
        case "paid":
          return {
            action: "captured",
            data: {
              session_id: (payment.metadata as Record<string, any>).session_id,
              amount: new BigNumber(payment.amount.value),
            },
          };
        case "authorized":
          return {
            action: "authorized",
            data: {
              session_id: (data.metadata as Record<string, any>).session_id,
              amount: new BigNumber(payment.amount.value),
            },
          };
        default:
          return { action: "not_supported" };
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return { action: "failed" };
    }
  }
}

export default MolliePaymentProviderService;

If you need any additional data, please let me know. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you!
